# Array with specific values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array the size of n where:
1/2 of the array is with a single (unknown) value.
1/4 of the array is with a single (unknown) different value.
And so on for 1/8, 1/16, 1/32
Give an algorithm to sort the array.
You cannot use the find median algorithm

So what I figured is:
There are only logn different values
There is a simple solution using a binary heap on O ( n*loglogn)
It looks like a question that needed to be solved in O (n)

Comment: That's true it's pretty similar to my solution

Comment: Absolutely not they are REAL numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use the Majority algorithm that takes O(n) then discovering what's the "half" value deleting it from the array and then doing it again on the new array
n+n/2+n/4+n/8+..... < 2n => O (n)

Comment: Please help here (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/is-optimal-solution-to-dual-not-unique-if-optimal-solution-to-the-primal-is-dege) in re here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095760/is-optimal-solution-to-dual-not-unique-if-optimal-solution-to-the-primal-is-dege) and here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/primal-degenerate-optimal-dual-unique-optimal)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible approach:

- scan the array and store element frequencies (there are log n distinct elements) in a hash table in [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) O(n) time; this is doable because [we can do insertions in amortized O(1) time](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec20.html);
- now run a classic sorting algorithm on these log n elements: this is doable in deterministic O(log n log log n) time using, say, heap sort or merge sort;
- now expand the sorted array---or create a new one and fill it using the sorted array and the hash table---using frequencies from the hash table; this is doable in O(n) amortized time.

The whole algorithm thus runs in amortized O(n) time, i.e., it is dominated by eliminating duplicates and expanding the sorted array. The space complexity is O(n).

This is essentially optimal because you need to "touch" all the elements to print the sorted array, which means we have a matching lower bound of Omega(n) on the running time.

Comment: The assumption that an hash table can be created in O(n) here isn't true. More specifically its not deterministic.

Comment: I think you mix up amortized and statistical. Unless you have a formal proof of that using potential functions which will surprise me

Comment: @OferMagen this is a well-known fact; see [this link](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec20.html), section "Analzing hash tables".

Comment: @blazs The O(1) bound is both randomized *and* amortized ("The worst-case performance of a hash table is the same as the underlying bucket data structure").

Answer (score 0):

Going over the array once, keep hash map for seen values. 
Like you said there are only `log(n)` different values.

Now you have list of all the different values  - sorting them will take `lon(n)*log(log(n))`

Once you have the sorted uniq like it's easy to constract the original array : The max value will take `n/2` cells , the 2nd take `n/4` and so on.

The Total run time is `O(n + lon(n)*log(log(n)) + n)` which is `O(n)`

Comment: It's not a binary tree and the time complexity is not the same as you wrote